# How to configure indentation tab length for a specific project in eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

In most of my projects I use the default value for indentation which is 4 spaces length.

In a specific project in the same workspace, I need to have each tab be 3 spaces length (stupid reasons).

I had a look through the project properties and did not find anything. Is there a hack or a plugin to achieve my goal ?

***Edit:*** I forgot to mension that the files that I'm editing are ***javascript files***, which are not affected by the customisations of the java code formatter for the project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the project, click project dropdown from menu bar, properties, Javascript, choose code style, formatter. Enable Project specific settings. Then you should be able to create a new profile for that project and change the tab width to be 3 spaces.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mension that the files that I'm editing are javascript files, which are not affected by the customisations of the java code formatter for the project (question edit), so this doesn't solve my problem. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Oh, indeed my answer is much less helpful then. @SamuelRossille Maybe add Javascript tag to grab more viewers and clarify the language (though your edit handles that)?